# Copying text to clipboard from webbrowser control (IE11)

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm trying to copy the visible text from a webbrowser control. Since I'm using windows 8 I can only test this using IE11, which might be the issue.

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, args) =>
{
    WebBrowser wbSender = s as WebBrowser;

    if (wbSender != null && wbSender.Document != null && 
        args.Url == wbSender.Document.Url)
    {
        //SelectAll seems to work fine
        wbSender.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);

        wbSender.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
        //string text = Clipboard.GetText();
    }

};
```

I know that similar code has worked in Windows 7 + IE10 earlier. So my question is if this is related to the browser/OS or if I missed something else.